# the code is doing its work but I'm not getting the desired output

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

whenever I click the delete button its works fine but I don't get the output like " deleted successfully  " its shows .then undefined..

```
const deleteThisCategory = (CategoryId) => {
  deleteCategory(CategoryId, user._id, token).then(data => {
    if (data.error) {
      console.log(data.error);
    } else {
      preload();
    }
  });
};
```

here is the delete category API call

```
export const deleteCategory = (userId, categoryId , token) => {
  fetch(`${API}/category/${categoryId}/${userId}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
   
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: you are returning the json output from API but deleteCategory is not a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this. deleteCategory needs to send only promise. Later where ever you are resolving you have to use then.

```
export const deleteCategory = (userId, categoryId , token) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/category/${categoryId}/${userId}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }
  })
};

const deleteThisCategory = (CategoryId) => {
  deleteCategory(CategoryId, user._id, token).then(data => {
      preload();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
};
```

Comment: @rohan - you are not displaying "deleted successfully"